# How do I make my home web server public when port 80 is forwarded with my CenturyLink router?

Tags: apache, ip-address, windows

I have the latest version of Apache Lounge, and I want to make it accessible to the other people. My Website IP is 192.168.0.61, and in `httpd.conf` these are the settings I added

```
Listen 192.168.0.61:80
ServerName 192.168.0.61:80
```

My virtual host settings are

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.61:80>
ServerName:192.168.0.61
ServerAlias:192.168.0.61
</VirtualHost>
```

I am running Windows 10, with a century link router. I have forwarded the port 80.

Comment: If you're forwarding port 80 on your external address to this internal IP address, it sounds like you've already made Apache publicly available at your external IP address. Typically you would also connect your domain name to your external IP address based on dynamic DNS. Is that the part you're asking about? Do you have a domain name?

Comment: My router won't let me forward my external address, and I've been trying to get a domain but I don't have on. I have a static ip btw

Comment: In port forwarding you tell the router which incoming messages from a specific port that you want to forward to some internal IP address/port. Normally the external and internal ports are the same, but they don't have to be.  Most routers, allow port forwarding to be restricted to incoming messages that originated from a specific external IP address. However, for most situations, you'll probably want to forward all incoming messages from any external IP.   In that situation, no external IP address is specified in port forwarding.

Answer (score 2):

It is public as soon as it becomes accessible from a public address. All you need is to forward a port from your gateway to your local machine.

You need to find out your external IP address. It could be static in which case, it will not change which makes things easier or it could be dynamic. In any case you have to configure your gateway to accept an incoming connection and forward it to an internal IP address and port. The most common is to forward port 80 which is the default for HTTP to port 80 on your webserver.

External visitors only need to access: `http://x.x.x.x/` to reach your website, where `x.x.x.x` is your external IP address. You can even forward a different port as some internet providers block certain ports. Visitors will then have to access the site by using `http://x.x.x.x:port/` where `port` is the one you forwarded.

Be sure that your local computer does not have a firewall rule to block port 80 though! The gateway can forward a port but your local computer must accept the connection.

Comment: is the external ip my private or public? My router won't let me forward my public ip because ```x.x.x.x``` is not a valid ip

Comment: When you browse to `whatsmyip.com` that will show you your external IP. It *must* be a public address for you to access the internet as response need to be sent to a public address.

Comment: My router doesn't let me forward the external ip, it keeps saying the it's not a valid ip, what should I do? I have port forwarded my internal ip, but I can't forward my external ip.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know that brand of routers but some times it is called something else like 'virtual server' or 'services'. Regardless you have to find a way to get a connection on your public address to reach your local server. If your router cannot do it, then you will need to use an external service to do tunneling which is when you connect out to an third party server and that one reroutes connects to it by others back as responses in your outbound connection.

Comment: It's a lot of effort for something that most routers can do, so maybe you will have yourself time and headaches just with a router upgrade. If cost is an issue, then you can look online for custom open-source router firmware that replaces the one that came with the router but allows more more features (while voiding your warranty, so this is a learning experience rather than a simple workaround).

Comment: It sounds to me like you msy be behind carrier grade nat (ie your router does not have any globally reachable address associated with it). If thats the case you will need your ISP to fix that, change ISP or use a VPN provider to provide you a static IP address through a vpn.

Comment: Centurylink is a pretty well known company, so it SHOULD have it, but i can't find it

Comment: CenturyLink has instructions for port forwarding here: https://www.centurylink.com/home/help/internet/modems-and-routers/advanced-setup/port-forwarding.html

Comment: "but I can't forward my external ip" - You mean the service is not available when using the external IP address from within your local network? (Have you tried from outside of your network?) This is an issue with _most_ consumer grade routers. The no-cost workaround is to use a local DNS/HOSTS file (to override the public DNS) that uses the local IP address instead - but you do need a domain name. You could also configure a subdomain in the public DNS that points to the local IP address - so that it's accessible from all devices on the local network.